# Probability the addition rule

Tags: probability, statistics

The percent distribution of the number of grandchildren for a sample of 1904 grandparents is shown in the pie chart. Find each probability. 
One- 9%
Two to four-36%
Five to seven- 23%
Eight or nine- 9%
Ten or more- 23%

a. Randomly selecting a grandparent with one grandchild.
b. Randomly selecting a grandparent with less than five grandchildren.
c. Randomly selecting a grandparent with two or more grandchildren.
d. Randomly selecting a grandparent with between two and seven grandchildren, inclusive.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please improve your question by adding your progress on the problem, or explaining what you are having difficulty with.

Comment: The point is that if $E$ and $F$ are **mutually exclusive** events (i.e. $E\cap F=\emptyset$, there is no overlap) then $Pr(E\cup F) = Pr(E) + Pr(F)$.  This stems from the inclusion-exclusion property that for *any* $E,F$ that $Pr(E\cup F) = Pr(E)+Pr(F) - Pr(E\cap F)$ and that $Pr(\emptyset)=0$.  Note in your problem, it is impossible to simultaneously be in multiple categories at the same time, hence they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(X=1) = 0.09

P(X < 5) = 0.09 + 0.36

P(X >= 2) = .36 + .23 + .09 + .23

P(2 <= X <= 7) = .36 + .23